# Django GROUP BY ForeignKey query

Tags: group-by

This is my models.py:

```
class QuestionCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    answer = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(QuestionCategory)
```

What I want to do is to get the questions and `group_by` the `QuestionCategory`

So I can display my questions like this:

- Question_Category (1)

  - Question (1)

    - Answer (1)
  - Question (2)

    - Answer (2)

  ....
- Question_Category (2)

  - Question (3)

    - Answer (3)
  - Question (...)

    - Answer (...)

  ...

This is the doc to my question: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `GROUP_BY`, just use [reverse foreignkey lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
categories = QuestionCategory.objects.prefetch_related('question_set').all()

for category in categories:
    print category.name
    for question in category.question_set.all():
        print question.question
        print question.answer
```

In your **views.py**

```
def questions(request):
    categories = QuestionCategory.objects.prefetch_related('question_set').all()
    return render(request, 'question.html', {
        'questions': questions
    })
```

In your **question.html**

```
{% for category in categories %}
  <h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
  {% for question in category.question_set.all %}
    <h3>{{ question.question }}</h3>
    <p>{{ question.answer }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) is use to optimise your query.